# How can I improve this regex?

Tags: regex

I am trying to write regex to check domain and path after it for some context value path. I wrote this regex which works. Is there any simple version for this without using or?

```
  ^/(creditcards|creditcards/.*)?$

    To match:    
    /    
    /creditcards    
    /creditcards/something
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^/(creditcards(/.*)?)?$
```